# Android speech recognition: startActivityForResult() does not work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dialog, speech

All you need to know:
I have a dialog with a button in it. When the button is pressed I want to start the speech recognition in my MainActivity. (The dialog is created by another class, I handle the clicks via an interface).

So here is the relevant code: (in MainActivity)

```
public void speechToText(boolean isName) {

    this.isName = isName;

    Intent intent = new Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault().toString());
    //intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, getString(R.string.prompt));

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "started acitvity for result",     //test toast
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_to_text_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if(isName)
                    currentName = text.get(0);
                else
                    currentDes = text.get(0);

                dialog.DialogNew(currentName, currentDes);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the problem: Normally a dialog appears for the input of speech. But somehow this dialog won't appear. I've tested it, and it shows the 'test toast' (see above), but there is no error and no input dialog. But Why?

**Edit:** I finally could test it on another device and (finally) I got an error: the google dialog was closed. From the protocol, a null pointer exception, so I guess there must be something wrong with my intent.

Comment: You need to check logcat for details, error details should appear there. Unfortunately the code you provided is not sufficient. It might be that you start this activity from other thread, you should start it from a main thread.

Comment: No errors in logcat. I have only one activity (in which I call the startActivityForResult(...)). As I said, I call speechToText() from a dialog. I thought there would be a problem, so i tried to dismiss it before I call the method, but that doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally could fix the problem:

In my manifast:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:uiOptions="none" >
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"> <!--THIS WON'T WORK-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Somehow you can't use singleInstance as the launch mode of the activity.
For my purpose I used singleTask as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need this:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
```

Android documentation lists this under "Required Extras" for RecognizerIntent.

EDIT: After experimentation though, it seems EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL is NOT mandatory in the Intent, contrary to the documentation. Recognition does work without it, at least in my test...

Comment: Sry I am currently not at home, but I check it asap :). I ignored this answer first, because I used exactly those methods in another app(in which I don't call it from a dialog) in which it worked.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I took your code, packaged in a default app skeleton, resolved the few undeclared class variables, and it works fine for me. I get recognition. Yes, even without "EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL".

Comment: @kryxion - I can only guess that maybe the language you are trying to use via "Locale.getDefault()" might not have workable Speech Input on your device. Check Settings->Language & Input->Voice input->(Lots of settings). If you try US English in your code it may work - It tends to come pre-installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it, but it doesn't work unfortunately. Maybe the problem is not in the code posted above, but maybe it is because I want to start it from an dialog. I also tried to avoid the interface, but that doesn't work neither.